# ExpandableListView's items get blended

Tags: android, expandablelistview

So I've made this application for dreams analysis and it works very well on the phones, but on tablets the information in explists get blended as you can see in the picture below.

That is, when you click on the group it should hide / show its children, but as you see, on tablets it just continues drawing the information one upon the other, like the display won't refresh its contents, I have no idea what to do, thus asking you for help.

[image: device-2016-10-26-094550.png]

The container layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/sExpList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" />

    <!-- FOR PORTRAIT LAYOUTS !-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/adLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The group element code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGroup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal_size" />

    <ImageButton

        android:id="@+id/sExp_BtnAdd"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btns_heigh"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btns_heigh"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="?attr/img_add" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The child element code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textChild"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal_size" />

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btns_heigh"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btns_heigh"
            android:id="@+id/sExp_BtnEdit"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="?attr/img_edit"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btns_heigh" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Movsar Bekaev
 * Date: 11.06.13
 * Time: 7:30
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class ActSignsManager extends cbActivity {


    ExpandableListView expListView;

    int selected_type;
    String[] cats;
    ArrayList<xSign> MySigns;
    _sManagerExpAdapter adapter;


    String[] catsMind;
    String[] catsAction;
    String[] catsForm;
    String[] catsCircumstances;


    private void cInitialization() {
        setContentView(R.layout.alay_signs_manager);

        catsMind = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.smanager_cats_mind);
        catsAction = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.smanager_cats_action);
        catsForm = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.smanager_cats_form);
        catsCircumstances = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.smanager_cats_circumstances);

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.sExpList);

        newSignFunc();
        readSigns();
        expFiller();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                String s = MySigns.get(SignIndexAt(selected_type, groupPosition, adapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString())).getTitle();
                Toast.makeText(ActSignsManager.this, String.valueOf(s), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        expListView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                String menuItems[];
                ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info =
                        (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
                int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
                int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
                int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);

                if (type == 0) {

                    menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.exp_menu_ongroup);
                    menu.setHeaderTitle(adapter.getGroupText(groupPos));
                    for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
                        menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
                    }
                }
                if (type == 1) {
                    String s = adapter.getChild(groupPos, childPos).toString();
                    menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.exp_menu_onchild);
                    menu.setHeaderTitle(s);
                    for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
                        menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        cInitialization();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
        int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
        int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);

        if (type == 0) {

            switch (menuItemIndex) {
                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent(ActSignsManager.this, ActSignsAddNew.class);
                    ps_int_params.put("Type", selected_type);
                    ps_string_arr_params.put("Categories", cats);
                    ps_int_params.put("Selected_Item", groupPos);

                    if (IS_FREE_VERSION && MySigns.size() > 69)
                        Toast.makeText(ActSignsManager.this, getString(R.string.ruefully_you_cant_add_another_sign), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else startActivity(i);

                    break;
            }
        }
        if (type == 1) {
            int index = SignIndexAt(selected_type, groupPos, adapter.getChild(groupPos, childPos).toString());

            switch (menuItemIndex) {
                case 0:
                    //     Toast.makeText(sManager.this, "edit", 5000).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(ActSignsManager.this, ActSignsAddNew.class);

                    ps_int_params.put("ID", MySigns.get(index).getID());
                    ps_string_params.put("Name", MySigns.get(index).getTitle());
                    ps_int_params.put("Type", MySigns.get(index).getType());
                    ps_int_params.put("Category", MySigns.get(index).getCategory());
                    ps_string_params.put("Note", MySigns.get(index).getNote());
                    ps_string_arr_params.put("Categories", cats);


                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    // нажатие на элемент

    void newSignFunc() {
        String type = ps_string_params.get("Type");
        if (type.equals("Mind")) {
            cats = catsMind;
            selected_type = 0;
        }
        if (type.equals("Action")) {
            cats = catsAction;
            selected_type = 1;
        }
        if (type.equals("Form")) {
            cats = catsForm;
            selected_type = 2;
        }
        if (type.equals("Circumstances")) {
            cats = catsCircumstances;
            selected_type = 3;
        }

    }

    private void readSigns() {
        MySigns = new ArrayList<xSign>();

        Cursor c = ps_db.query(const_tbl_signs, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    xSign iSingleSign = new xSign();
                    iSingleSign.setID(c.getInt(DBI_SIGNS_ID));
                    iSingleSign.setHash(c.getString(DBI_SIGNS_HASH));
                    iSingleSign.setTitle(c.getString(DBI_SIGNS_TITLE));
                    iSingleSign.setType(c.getInt(DBI_SIGNS_TYPE));
                    iSingleSign.setCategory(c.getInt(DBI_SIGNS_CATEGORY));
                    iSingleSign.setNote(c.getString(DBI_SIGNS_NOTE));
                    MySigns.add(iSingleSign);
                    Log.d("777", iSingleSign.getID() + "||| cat:" + iSingleSign.getCategory() + "||| type:" + iSingleSign.getType());
                } while (c.moveToNext());
                c.close();
            } else
                Log.d("777", "0 rows");
        }


    }


    private int SignIndexAt(int type, int category, String name) {
        boolean exist = false;
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.MySigns.size(); i++) {
            if (this.MySigns.get(i).getTitle().equals(name) && this.MySigns.get(i).getCategory() == category && this.MySigns.get(i).getType() == type) {
                index = i;
                exist = true;
            }
        }
        if (exist) {
            return index;
        } else {
            return 999999;
        }
    }

    private boolean removeSign(int index) {
        ps_db.delete(const_tbl_signs, "id = " + MySigns.get(index).getID(), null);

        Toast.makeText(ActSignsManager.this, getString(R.string.messages_sign_removed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Refresh main activity upon close of dialog box

        readSigns();
        expFiller();

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }

    private void expFiller() {
        ArrayList<String> tmp;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groups = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
            tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (xSign sign : MySigns) {
                if (sign.getCategory() == i && sign.getType() == selected_type)
                    tmp.add(sign.getTitle());
            }
            groups.add(tmp);
        }
        //Создаем адаптер и передаем context и список с данными
        adapter = new _sManagerExpAdapter(this, cats, groups);
        expListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cInitialization();
        showAds();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        cInitialization();
        showAds();
    }

    public class _sManagerExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mGroups;
        private Context mContext;
        private String[] cats;

        public _sManagerExpAdapter(Context context, String[] categories, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groups) {
            mContext = context;
            mGroups = groups;
            cats = categories;
        }


        public String getGroupText(int groupPosition) {
            return cats[groupPosition];
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return mGroups.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return mGroups.get(groupPosition).size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return mGroups.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return mGroups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                                 ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.s_exp_group_view, null);
            }

            if (isExpanded) {
                //Изменяем что-нибудь, если текущая Group раскрыта
            } else {
                //Изменяем что-нибудь, если текущая Group скрыта
            }

            TextView textGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGroup);
            textGroup.setText(cats[groupPosition] + " [" + String.valueOf(this.getChildrenCount(groupPosition)) + "]");

            ImageView btnAddSigns = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sExp_BtnAdd);
            btnAddSigns.setFocusable(false);
            final int gPos = groupPosition;

            btnAddSigns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ActSignsManager.this, ActSignsAddNew.class);
                    ps_int_params.put("Type", selected_type);
                    ps_string_arr_params.put("Categories", cats);
                    ps_int_params.put("Selected_Item", gPos);

                    if (IS_FREE_VERSION && MySigns.size() > 69)
                        Toast.makeText(ActSignsManager.this, getString(R.string.ruefully_you_cant_add_another_sign), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            return convertView;

        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.s_exp_child_view, null);
            }

            TextView textChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textChild);
            textChild.setText(mGroups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));

            final int index = SignIndexAt(selected_type, groupPosition, adapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

            ImageView btnEditSign = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sExp_BtnEdit);
            btnEditSign.setFocusable(false);


            btnEditSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ActSignsManager.this, ActSignsAddNew.class);

                    ps_int_params.put("ID", MySigns.get(index).getID());
                    ps_string_params.put("Name", MySigns.get(index).getTitle());
                    ps_int_params.put("Type", MySigns.get(index).getType());
                    ps_int_params.put("Category", MySigns.get(index).getCategory());
                    ps_string_params.put("Note", MySigns.get(index).getNote());
                    ps_string_arr_params.put("Categories", cats);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found the answer, and here it is - you should explicitly set a background for the layout, and it is not important whether you set it to explist or root element, it just must be set.

It didn't start to work with any of proposed solutions unless I had set a background in the activity's layout which holds the explist.

Interesting question - why does this work?!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working but the error I was getting was slightly different than yours.

When I tried to use your layouts (minus the resources I did not have) the `ImageButton`s in both `group_element.xml` and `child_element.xml` were somehow capturing `MotionEvent`s in the whole row (when they shouldn't) and in my case it was messing with the expanding of the layout.

Solution: I just the two `ImageButton` for two `ImageView`, and build `OnTouchListener`s for the two views. As you can see it is running on a Nexus 7 emulator.

Because I don't have you dataset and most importantly the **adapter code** I cannot say for sure that this will fix your problem.

[image]

Ps in case you are interested I have tested your XML on customized version of JournalDev's adapter example on [ExpandableListViews](http://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

    public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                       HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {

            //---------------------------------------------
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_element, null);
        }
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textChild);
        expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);

        ImageView editViewBtn = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sExp_BtnEdit);
        editViewBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                // do stuff

                return false;
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_element, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textGroup);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        ImageView addV = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sExp_BtnAdd);
        addV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        addV.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                // do stuff

                return false;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The dummy data generator:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableListDataPump {
    public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> ego = new ArrayList<String>();
        ego.add("dream 1");
        ego.add("dream 2");
        ego.add("dream 3");
        ego.add("dream 4");
        ego.add("dream 5");

        List<String> personalities = new ArrayList<String>();
        personalities.add("dream 1");
        personalities.add("dream 2");
        personalities.add("dream 3");
        personalities.add("dream 4");

        List<String> places = new ArrayList<String>();
        places.add("dream 1");
        places.add("dream 2");
        places.add("dream 3");
        places.add("dream 4");
        places.add("dream 5");

        expandableListDetail.put("Form of the ego", ego);
        expandableListDetail.put("Form of other personalities", personalities);
        expandableListDetail.put("Place's form", places);
        return expandableListDetail;
    }
}
```

The main activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    List<String> expandableListTitle;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.sExpList);
        expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
        expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                                + " -> "
                                + expandableListDetail.get(
                                expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Your slightly changed main xml, don't forget to switch from `ImageButton` to `ImageView`:
(I changed some of the resources and dimensions that you did not share)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/sExpList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" />

    <!-- FOR PORTRAIT LAYOUTS !-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/adLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Group xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/sExp_BtnAdd"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</LinearLayout>
```

child xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textChild"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:id="@+id/sExp_BtnEdit"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Uff... this was a long one, hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, I have done what you proposed - replaced Buttons with Views and had added onTouch events, but unfortunately my results didn't change. I added my activity's code, please review it maybe you'll find something wrong there.

Comment: Even though you didn't answer my comment, your answer shows that you gave a real try to this problem and simulated it to find out what was going on, and although it didn't help me (see the accepted answer), I decided to give you the bounty :)

Comment: Thank you @movsar that is very kind of you. You are absolutely right, sorry for not getting back at you. After reading the accepted answer i also don't know why the issue is  the background, but i couldn't reproduce the exact same problem you had, food for thought? Once Again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your root layouts params in both list items from

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Android is designed for multiple screens, so sometimes one single layout file could not support some screens well. A suggestion may help you:

**make some adjustments on the original item's layout file, make it on the tablet right, then save and put the adjusted file in the corresponding directory as follows:**

```
 res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
 res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

*And xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp, 
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp, 
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp, 
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp.*

Official documents about this topic here, https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Which I thought is a better solution for dealing with unusual behavior on ordinary layouts.